# Django saying that my syntax is wrong

Tags: python, django, syntax, module

Basically working with django and it keeps telling me that there's a syntax error in this code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from venues import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),

    # ex /venues/3
    url(r'^(?P<venue_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /venues/3/events
    url(r'^(?P<venue_id>\d+)/events/$', views.events, name='events')
)
```

Specifically it seems to be telling me that the:

```
from venues import views
```

line is incorrect.

However my venues/views.py looks like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello this is the home page!")

def detail(request, venue_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at Venue %s.", % venue_id)

def events(request, venue_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at events at venue %s.", % venue_id)
```

So the file exists and seems to be doing just fine until I start using venue_id in the urls.py

Oh and just for good measure my main urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Comedy.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^Comedy/', include('Comedy.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^venues/', include('venues.urls')),
)
```

So I'm not entirely sure where the issue is coming from, all help appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Me.

Comment: Please, include the *full* traceback of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `view.py` file does have syntax errors:

```
return HttpResponse("You're looking at Venue %s.", % venue_id)
```

and

```
return HttpResponse("You're looking at events at venue %s.", % venue_id)
```

have commas between the string and the `%` string formatting operator, and that is not legal python syntax. Remove the commas before the `%` operators.

Please, in future, always include the *full* python traceback when reporting a problem with your Python code, that saves us from having to guess what your problem is.

Comment: Just accepted, I'm pretty new to stackoverflow (Well using it that is) so am still learning the ins and outs such as accepting answers

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here:

```
def detail(request, venue_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at Venue %s.", % venue_id)

def events(request, venue_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at events at venue %s.", % venue_id)
```

you have to remove the comma before the % venue_id.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
def events(request, venue_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at events at venue %s.", % venue_id)
```

try:

```
def events(request, venue_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at events at venue %s.")  % venue_id
```